# Import 3 google spreadsheet at same time into another

Tags: google-apps-script, import, spreadsheet

With this script, I can import one spreadsheet into another spreadsheet in a tab.

```
function importA() {
var values1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxurl').
  getSheetByName('xxxname').getRange('A1:DE300').getValues(); 
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('TAB').
  getRange(1,1,values1.length,values1[0].length).setValues(values1)
  }
```

Now, I would like to import 3 spreadsheets one below the other (in the same tab), preserving any increase in the rows of each sheet at the same time.

How could I proceed?

Comment: Just to confirm, "preserving any increase in the rows of each sheet at the same time." does this mean that any additional rows added on each of the 3 spreadsheets should automatically update on the destination spreadsheet, is that correct?

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample expected output as well as a demo sheet with dummy values?

Comment: @DiegoSanchez thanks for your reply! The 3 spreadsheets have different urls and I would import a specific tab from them (TAB1, TAB2, TAB3). The output must be on the new spreadsheet in the tab named TAB.

Comment: If (for example) the 1st spreadsheet has 4 rows, the 2nd spreadsheet 4 rows, the 3rd spreadsheet 4 rows.. Then when (for example) 1st spreadsheet increase of 1 row, the other two go bottom of 1 row, and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code and see if it works for you:

```
    function collectAll() {

    createNew(); //this can be removed for instances that you would need to run the two functions separately.
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ["TAB1","TAB2","TAB3"];
    for( var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++ ) {
     if (sheets[i] == "TAB1"){
       var sh = ss.getSheetByName('TAB1');
       var range1 = sh.getRange(1,1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
       Logger.log(range1);
     }
     else if (sheets[i] == "TAB2"){
       var sh = ss.getSheetByName('TAB2');
       var range2 = sh.getRange(1,1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
       Logger.log(range2);
     }
     else if (sheets[i] = "TAB3"){
     var sh = ss.getSheetByName('TAB3');
     var range3 = sh.getRange(1,1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
       Logger.log(range3);
     }
    }
    var range = range1.concat(range2,range3);
    Logger.log(range);
    ss.getSheetByName('TAB').getRange(1,1, range.length, sh.getLastColumn()).setValues(range);
}

function createNew() { //This function creates the Tabs from 3 different sheets using Sheet ID
  var sheets = ["ID1","ID2","ID3"]; //Spreadsheet ID goes here
  for (i=0; i<sheets.length; i++ ) {
  var ssh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheets[i]);
  var values = ssh.getSheetValues(1,1, ssh.getLastRow(), ssh.getLastColumn());
  var create = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().insertSheet('TAB'+(1+i));
  create.getRange(1,1, ssh.getLastRow(), ssh.getLastColumn()).setValues(values);
  Logger.log(create);
  }
}
```

What this does is that it assigns all of the values of each tab to its own variable `range1`, `range2` and `range3` and then it concatenates all values in a single `range`, then sets the value to the sheet named "TAB".

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply, Where I have to insert the 3 urls of the 3 different spreadsheets in your code?

Comment: Hello @Gavis, I edited my code above, please see the inline comments

Answer (score 0):

I've used getSheetByName instead of openByID but you can get the idea.

```
function test() {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"];
    for( var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++ ) {
      importA(sheets[i]);
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

function importA(name) {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("TAB");
    sh1.clear() // if you want to erase old data in TAB
    var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    var r1 = sh1.getDataRange();
    var r2 = sh2.getDataRange();
    // to prevent a blank line at the top
    var i = r1.getNumRows() === 1 ? 0 : 1;
    sh1.getRange(r1.getNumRows()+i,1,r2.getNumRows(),r2.getNumColumns()).setValues(r2.getValues());
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: TheWizEd please see my comments..

Answer (score 0):

#### Merge all spreadsheets sheets into one sheet

```
function mergeSpreadsheetsAllIntoOneSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'].forEach((id, i) => {
    let sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    sss.getSheets().forEach(sh => {
      let vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
      let a = [...Array.from(new Array(vs[0].length).keys(), x => (x == 0)?sss.getName():sh.getName())];
      vs.unshift(a);
      let ash = ss.getSheets()[0];
      if (vs && vs.length > 0) {
        ash.getRange(ash.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Cooper please see my comments